# jQuery - exposing events

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I'm trying to write my own jQuery plugin.  My goal is to attach it to a form to override submission.  I have the basics down, but my problem lies in "exposing" events.

Here is what I want to do:

```
$('#myobject').myplugin({

    setting1: 'somevalue',
    beforesubmit: function(){ ... }

});
```

Here's what I have so far

```
$.fn.myplugin= function (options) {

    var settings = {
        setting1: '',
        beforesubmit: function() { return true; }
    };

    return this.each(function () {
        // If options exist, lets merge them
        // with our default settings
        if (options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }

        //fire beforesubmit

        $(this).live("submit", function(){

            //do stuff
        }

    });

};
```

The ?? lies in how I fire the event off.  I want to have other events too, like onerror, aftersubmit, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just call the method, replacing this:

```
//fire beforesubmit
```

With this:

```
if(settings.beforesubmit) settings.beforeSubmit();
```

You can also do this, adding whatever callback parameters you want, for example:

```
if(settings.beforesubmit) settings.beforeSubmit.call(this, someVariable);
```

---

An alternative (not appropriate for some situations) is to trigger your own events and let the jQuery binding model do the work, for example:

```
$(this).trigger("beforeSubmit");
```

Then elsewhere, bind to the event, for example:

```
$(".someElement").bind("beforeSubmit", function() { alert("submit!"); });
```